# MKMapView inside UITableViewCell crashes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mkmapview

I have an issue with a mapview inside a tableview cell. I get the following error when loading the view:

```
2016-03-30 23:14:34.773 App[5006:303995] -[UITableViewCellContentView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faad14920d0
2016-03-30 23:14:34.779 App[5006:303995] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCellContentView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7faad14920d0'
```

This is the code for the UITableViewCell:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        mapView.delegate = self

        mapView.userInteractionEnabled = false
    }
}
```

But when I remove the line `mapView.delegate = self`, the app didn't crash. But then I can't manipulate the map?

I also tried setting delegate with Storyboard, but I got the same error message, and the app crashed.

Comment: Looks like your `mapView` outlet is hooked up to the wrong view

Comment: Good catch @dan ! Thanks a lot!